# First occurrence of one item from given string array

Tags: c#, string

I am lookin for way to get the index of the first occurrence of **one** item from giveמ string array:

for example:

I have the following array:

```
 string[] dlimiterArray =  { ":", ".", ",", " ", "-", ";" };
```

and also have the following string:

```
string data = "hi hi bla bla bla user:myusername. bla bla bla";
```

and I would like to do get the first time that **one** of the dlimiterArray items Appears

Comment: I'm not very familiar with c#, but the pseudo code would go something like this: `iterate through each element in the string. if the current element matches any string in dlimiterArray, return the position.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`String.IndexOfAny`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11w09h50.aspx):

```
int index = data.IndexOfAny(dlimiterArray);
```

However, you'll also want to change `dlimiterArray` to a `char[]`, not a `string[]`:

```
char[] dlimiterArray =  { ':', '.', ',', ' ', '-', ';' };
```